# Бесконечный парсинг по дате

Tags: python, парсер, циклы

Хочу парсить себе ссылку на футбольную трансляцию. Есть функция которая парсит дату и время трансляции. Также есть функия которая парсит ссылку на трансляцию.
Вопрос такой: как организовать парсинг трансляции имея дату а по завершении трансляции снова получить дату и исходя из нее в нужное время снова получить трансляцию. И так бесконечно.

Посоветуйте с какой стороны подойти к решению этого вопроса, в какую сторону смотреть.

Я понимаю что можно например проверять текущую дату и сравнивать с датой трансляции и если совпадает то парсить ссылку на трансляцию. Меня больше интересует как потом все это повторять бесконечно? Получение даты- сравнение- получение ссылки на трансляцию

Comment: `while True: ...`

Comment: Приведите хотя бы псевдокод какой-то, как это у вас устроено, какова структура кода, так не очень понятно, как советовать что-то